# Output using readlines in Python

Tags: python, readlines

I was wondering if anyone had an answer for this. In the image the top case has the code,

output of the two different lines of code from below:
[image]

```
def stats ():
    inFile = open('textFile.txt', 'r')
    line = inFile.readlines()
    print(line[0])
```

and the second case has the code,

```
def stats ():
    inFile = open('textFile.txt', 'r')
    line = inFile.readlines()
    print(line[0:1])
```

instead of going to the next iteration and printing it, it just spits out the iteration, now populated with all the \t and the end of line character \n. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: It's because you are printing a list instead of a string. Both versions include the \t, the string print just interprets them into tab characters.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you're printing a single line, which is a string.

In the second case you're printing a slice of a list, which is also a list.  The strings contained within the list use `repr` instead of `str` when printed, which changes the representation.  You should loop through the list and print each string separately to fix this.

```
>>> s='a\tstring\n'
>>> print(str(s))
a   string

>>> print(repr(s))
'a\tstring\n'

>>> print(s)
a   string

>>> print([s])
['a\tstring\n']
```

Comment: ahh I see what you're saying. Thank you. I changed the code to



    def stats():
        inFile = open('textFile.txt', 'r')
        lines = inFile.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            print(line)

and it worked. thanks again